# Problemas com o Psycopg2 no MAC

Tags: python

Estou apanhando com o Python + Postgre e Psycopg2.

Instalei o Python 3.4 no meu MAC, depois o Postgre e em seguida segui os seguintes passos:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin:$PATH
pip install psycopg2
```

Ele instalou o Psycopg 2, porém quando dou um import eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 /Users/leandro/PycharmProjects/Teste/teste.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leandro/PycharmProjects/Teste/teste.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Na web eu achei referencias para fazer o seguinte:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib.old 
sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib
```

ou

```
sudo ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/lib
```

Porém não resolveu … Alguma dica?

Comment: Minha dica seria instalar tudo isso num ambiente isolado e não direto no Mac OS, procure por virtualenv.

Comment: Eu também lhe recomendo usar o virtualenv, crie um venv com python3 e tente rodar o pip com o venv ativo, muito provavelmente resolva seu problema.

Comment: No virtualenv ele reclama que não acha o pg_config apesar de já ter configurado no path o caminho.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não trabalho com *Psycopg2* então minha resposta é mais genérica, que pode ajudar com esse tipo de problema.

Como você está adicionando algo ao `PATH` antes de instalar, é possível que essa mesma modificação seja necessária permanentemente, ou pelo menos sempre antes de executar algum programa que vá utilizar esse componente.

Uma alternativa simples é criar ou modificar o seu arquivo **.bashrc** (em */Users/leandro/.bashrc*) adicionando aquela mesma linha:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin:$PATH
```

Abra uma nova aba ou janela do Terminal.

Se você houver substituído o Python default do seu Mac com 3.4, eu sugeriria executar o `pip` com `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

Se você, ao contrário, estiver usando `virtualenv`, lembre-se de ativá-lo antes de instalar:

```
cd ~/PycharmProjects/Teste
source nome-do-env/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2
```

Imagino que agora você possa executar seu programa nesse mesmo Terminal:

```
sudo python ~/PycharmProjects/Teste/teste.py
```

**Uma outra opção**. Como você parece estar utilizando **PyCharm**, dê uma olhada nas configurações de execução: menu `Run` > `Edit configurations...`. Ache a configuração que você está utilizando para executar seu programa, edite o campo `Environment variables`, adicionando um novo valor: *Name* = `PATH`, *Value* = `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin:$PATH`. Assim, sempre que PyCharm for executar seu programa, o valor de `PATH` será o mesmo valor modificado que você utilizou para instalar *Psycopg2*.

Comment: Grato! Estes foram os passos que segui, fiz a instalação em um virtualenv e fora. Testei em duas máquinas diferentes e o problema no OSX parece ser o mesmo.